# error using loop on custom function

Tags: r, function, loops

I am having some trouble debugging this issue can someone please let me know where I am going wrong?

I have this simple function created that will be used on multiple dataframes to get the same information

```
TransCleaning <- function(df){
  x <- select(df, a, b, c, d, e, f, g) %>% filter(e != "$0.00")
return(x)
}
```

since the names of the dataframes this function will be used on should stay the same, I could easily just hard code it but I was a loop.

so I make a list of my dataframes after making their names shorter.

```
files2 <- c(substr(files,5,10)
```

Then I try and run through this loop

```
for(i in 1:length(files2))
{
 clean=TransCleaning(files2[i])
 assign(files2[i], clean)
}
```

I get the following error. it has something to do with calling the files2 list because

```
Transclean(files2[1])
```

does not work either, while

```
Transclean(df)
```

works fine.

The error I am getting when I run the loop and transclean(files2[1]) is as follows:

```
Error in UseMethod("select_") : 
no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Comment: I think you need to first read the files with `read.csv/read.table` before applying the functions.  If it is the string name of data.frame, then `get` the value of dataset using `get` or `mget` (to return a list of data.frames)

Comment: Reading the csvs is my first step. it happens before calling the function. when the function is ran, all the dataframes are in the global environment.

Comment: As I commented above, then your have object names as strings, so you need `get` to get the value out of it. ie. `TransCleaning(get(files2[i]))`

Comment: You're absolutely right! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function, the values of the data.frame string objects are not returned, so we can use `get` to do this

```
for(i in 1:length(files2)){
   clean <- TransCleaning(get(files2[i]))
    assign(files2[i], clean)
}
```

Though, it is better not to create objects in the global environment as it can be read directly into `list` and then functions can be applied on `list` instead of having lots of objects in global env.